# PROPER PHP CONFORMITY Functions, or classes for my project

Tags: php, arrays, function, class, recursion

I am trying to determine if I should go with functions or classes for my project.  For what little I am doing I think functions are better but I wanted the opinion of others to see what is the best way to go.

Here is the problem and I know how to code I just need to know what is the best way to go.

I have 4 variables I am working with at a time but from an array of about 10,000.

```
$image_Name
$image_Small
$image_Medium
$image_Large
```

1. I need to make sure that image small, medium, large are not null or blank.
2. I need to check to see if file exists
3. I need to get image height.

I then after all the above is done I need to make sure that image small, medium and large are correct based on image height.

I was thinking about using just 2 functions, but then thought about it and figured maybe a class would be better.

Create an image class and give it properties of name, small, medium, large, exists, valid and pass to the class the data as an array.  And then return the output only.

Would a class be overdoing such a simple project?

Comment: Functions and classes are not interchangeable. A single class would not be overkill. 20 classes would be. But would this class do something more than a plain array? If not, don't build it.

Comment: I understand that classes and functions are not interchangeable.  I can do this project by setting up multiple variables and storing the results in them from functions do my output and reuse them and start all over again.

Comment: Or I can create a class to keep variables low by creating properties instead of individual variables if I were doing it with functions.

Comment: The only thing I am going to do is if do a basic output to tell me if images exist for small medium and large and if the small image is really the smallest and the largest really the largest by getting the image height if the file exists and is not null or blank.  I would be working if I chose to do a class a multi-dimensional array.    4 items, 10000 times.

Comment: It seems to me that you should write the code and then ask this question (with code) at http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Well that defeats the purpose then.  Write 2 different versions then ask which is better.  I wanted to save development time and get a consensus on the issue to see which way would be the better of the 2 and then write my code.  The code runs in under 2 minutes time, so I am not looking for what runs better but more so what would be the PROPER PHP CONFORMED way of writing it.

Comment: Considering that we are having this conversation because you cannot confidently decide on your own at this time, IMHO building both versions will be beneficial for you (even though that's not what I had in mind -- I was thinking about writing one version). Asking is good, but the only way to really learn programming is by doing.

Comment: Furthermore, document yourself on the benefits and disadvantages of functional programming over object-oriented programming.

Comment: Okay I totally get it.  I think.  The light-bulb finally went on when to comes to OOP.  I understand it, I get it verses functions and recursions.  The one thing I do remember is that I was told and read on numerous occasions that OOP is not the solution for everything.  I know how to write the code without OOP and with OOP.  I guess I am more concerned that since I am going to distribute it and I have a feeling to thousands of people I wanted to make sure that my code was written to the conformity and proper framework of what php coding is suppose to be.

Comment: After the code was written then I was going to submit for review / suggestions, because I want my code to be the best that it possibly can be if I am going to distribute it.